# Objective C class reference as property

Tags: objective-c, class, reference, properties

This should be easy as hell, but I can't figure out the syntax on my own.

Couldn't really formulate the question correctly so I couldn't Google the answer. (you can get why with keywords like objective c, property, class)

Anyhow. In one of my classes I want to save a property which references another class, NOT an instance of another class. Which you easily can accomplish with this code:
`@property (nonatomic, assign) Class anotherClass;`

Although, I don't want to use the generic `Class`. I want to use my own classes, but I can't figure how, guess I'd like to do something like `@property (nonatomic, assign) @class(MyOwnClass) myClass;`

Comment: I don't see the point of this.

Comment: I do. One would only be able to assign classes that are his class or descendants of that class, not just _any_ class. Probably against the dynamic philosophy, but could be useful, at times.

Comment: Aha, descendants. Well that would be easy with a custom setter.

Comment: He can assign classes or descendants as long as it was a pointer.  You just can't use a class without a pointer for this.

Comment: But that would decide at runtime. What he wants is something that doesn't allow it at compile time. As I said, probably against the dynamic principle.

Comment: He doesn't want to assign _instances_, he wants to assign _classes_ in a certain hierarchy.

Comment: Oh wait. now I see what you mean. He probably means `Class *anotherClass`, etc. Sorry, but coming from Delphi I sometimes forget that references like this must be declared as pointers in ObjC.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys. I like watching your discussion as well.  

And yeah. Really, there was no _need_ to do like that. I ended up just using a pointer (`<code>@property (nonatomic, assign) MyClass *myClassReference;</code>`) and using the `<code>[MyClass class]</code>`-object when assigning it.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If we are talking about descendants, why don't you use a protocol and declare a property of type id<MyProperty>. That way you get more reusable code as any object, an instance of an object though, that conforms to the methods declared in that protocol is supported to be assigned to the property. If you then make a base class, MyClass, that implements all these methods, then all subclasses of MyClass will also conform to the protocol and is therefore assignable. It would still be instances though. I don't se the purpose of referencing the class itself.

Comment: I'm working it Core Data, `NSManagedObject`-descendants. In different scenarios I want to work with different coredata-models in the class I'm referring too, and these models should all descent from the same abstract class (`MyOwnClass` in the example above).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objective-C does not allow for stack based objects.  I don't think you'll be able to do this.  You'll have to store a pointer to an instance of a class.  [class is a method of NSObject, and returns a Class object, which is an instance of meta-class.](http://chachatelier.fr/programmation/fichiers/cpp-objc-en.pdf)  This is why it works with just class, because you're saving the instance of the meta class object.

Comment: I don't get it. Where are stack based objects mentioned? ISTM he simply wants to expose a class varialbe that only "takes" his class or descendants of it, instead of the generic Class type. This is, e.g., possible in Delphi (`class of MyClass`), and ISTM he wants to know if it is possible in ObjC too.

Comment: He would have to do, MyClass * to take an instance of a class.

Comment: See other comment: not an instance; he wants metadata about only his class or descendants to be assigned there. Anyway, +1.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this using protocols. Declare your Class property to be a Class object conforming to your new protocol (it need't even have methods), e.g.

```
@protocol MyProtocol
@end

@property (nonatomic, assign) Class<MyProtocol> anotherClass;
```

Now simply declare conformance to MyProtocol in all base classes you wish  to accept for anotherClass.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom setter which raises an NSInvalidArgumentException exception if the value isn't the class you are looking for. You need to use `Class`.

Due to the fact that every object or class argument is `id` in Objective-C you can't raise a compile error, just document your code well.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C doesn't have anything like templates or [covariant/contravariant return types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29).  There's no way to say "I want to return a `Class` object which represents a class which is a subclass of `MyOwnClass`."  You have to use the generic `Class` pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am confused, but couldn't you do this?

Temp.h

```
@interface Temp : NSObject
    NSString *myString;
@end
@property(nonatomic,assign) NSString *myString;
```

Temp.m

```
#import "Temp.h"
@synthesize myString;
```

MyNewClass.h

```
#import "Temp.h"
@interface MyNewClass : NSObject
{
}
-(NSString) returnTemp;
@end
```

MyNewClass.m

```
#import "MyNewClass.h"
- (NSString) returnTemp
{
    Temp *myTemp = [[Temp alloc] init];
    [myTemp setMyString:@"hello"];
    return myTemp;
}
```